# delay between function in loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that shows modal boxes:

```
function ShowAnonce(){
    ...
    jQuery(".ShowAnonce").show();
    jQuery(".ShowAnonce").animate({opacity: 1},300).delay(1800).animate({opacity: 0},300);
}
```

And what I want to do is to show this box 10 times with different random intervals. I used a `for` loop and `setTimeout` like this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){  
    setTimeout(ShowAnonce(),Math.random()*100);
}
```

but it shows the box 10 times with no delay. What can I do to fix it?

Also, why can't I do the following at the end of `ShowAnonce` function?

```
    jQuery(".ShowAnonce").hide();
```

If I do it, it doesn't shows me box because style `display:none` keeps being assigned.

Comment: use `setTimeout(ShowAnonce, Math.random()*100);` instead of `setTimeout(ShowAnonce(),Math.random()*100);`

Comment: you should pass the function but you passed the return value (`undefined`)

Comment: Just as @marcel writes. If you use "()" after your function it will be called when the browser gets there. You have to use just the name of the function.

Comment: ok, I fixed it. But setTimeout works only for a first time. So I have delay, for example 8 second, when it's expired it begen to show boxes without no delay

Comment: @dantey89, did you want [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/v10L60L7/1/)? Let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() can return value in decimals also like , 0.123. Which the setTimeout() cannot take . Try Math.ceil (Math.random()) this will give you an integer but might give the same value again and again . 
I would try (Math.ceil (Math.random()) *10 ).

Comment: You messed up your brackets, `Math.ceil (Math.random()) *10`  will just give you 10 every time.

Comment: Yeah I was typing from mobile sorry .

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use `setInterval` as below instead of for loop for `x` number of times:

```
var x = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
   ShowAnnounce();
   if (++x === 10) {
       window.clearInterval(intervalID);
   }
}, Math.random()*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another post about each() iteration gave me an answer. So it works for me:

```
    var time = 0;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        time = time + Math.random() *10000;
        setTimeout(ShowAnonce, time);
    }
```